# How can I determine eigen values of $M+J$ from above?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have a block diagonal matrix of the form $M+J$ where $M$ and $J$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $J$ is a matrix whose all entries are equal to $1$.

Also $M+J$ has blocks of the following form:

1. \begin{bmatrix} n-1 && 1 \\1 && n-1 \end{bmatrix} appearing $p$ times and
2. $nI_{n-2p}$ appearing once.

I am having two problems :

1. How can I determine eigen values of $M+J$ from above ?
2. Is it possible to determine eigen values of $M$ using the above information?

Any help will be highly useful.

Comment: Are you saying that $M+J$ is block diagonal, or that $M$ is block diagonal?

Comment: Note that the eigenvalues of a block diagonal matrix are precisely the eigenvalues of each block.

Comment: M+J is block diagonal@Omnomnomnom